# How to disable radiobuttons and checkboxes produced by HtmlHelper methods in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, radio-button, html-helper

I have a series of pages (in a wizard type application). After collecting user's inputs here and there, I'd like to display a summary in a single page. I don't want the users to modify information on that page, just to visualize them. Otherwise, he they go back to the previous pages to do so.

To obtain that, I use **Html.Encode(Model.field)** to replace textbox. But I don't want  to replace checkboxes and radiobuttons; I'm gonna need to disable them. But,

**How do I disable Radiobutton and checkboxes when using HtmlHelper methods?**

```
<%Html.CheckBox("MyCheckBox")%>
```

or

```
<%Html.RadioButton("MyRadioButton")%>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the HTML attribute `disabled`:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("MyCheckbox", new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
<%: Html.RadioButton("MyRadioButton", value, new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```

Comment: I've learn also how to talk to Html from your answer. In case you speak french: Merci, je m'attendais pas a retrouver des francophones dans ce site. Et bien, c'est fait.